# Google reCaptcha attribute 'data-callback' causing page refresh on alert

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I have added Google reCaptcha v3 script to my form. The form also includes validation that alerts the user to complete the input field. Now when the user clicks on submit button directly, an alert is shown and when OK is clicked the page refreshes and form data is submitted in the backend. I have tried adding return false and e.preventdefault() in the function but the page still resets after the alert. If I try to add any additional condition to the data-callback function, the submit button stops working.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head> 
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
 <script>
   function onSubmit(token) {
     document.getElementById("demo-form").submit();
   }
 </script>
<script>

function validateForm() {
  var fname = document.forms.WebForm.fname.value;

  if (fname == "") {
     
    alert("Please fill out all the fields");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
 </head>
  <body>
    </style>
    <div class="container">
      <form action="https://www.samepage.com" method="post" id="demo-form" name="WebForm">
        <div>         
          <div>
            <input name="fname" id="fname" type="text" placeholder="First name*" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div>
               <div>
                 <input type = "submit" style = "font-weight: bold;" value="Submit" class="g-recaptcha button" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
                   data-callback='onSubmit'
                   data-action='submit' 
                   onClick="return validateForm()"/>
               </div>
            </div>
      </form>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Even the required attribute in the input tag doesn't work with the recaptcha script added. When I remove the data-callback attribute and the supporting script functions, the alert and form works as expected.

Comment: function validateForm(event)  { event.preventDefault() }

Comment: I tried this as well, the page still submits after the alert.